# How I can identify duplicate in dataset and tag it by insert a column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

My dataset is like this:

| ExecutionTime | Code | Amount | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09102021D081020 | HUUSNJUNJ | 500000 | C |
| 09102021D081020 | HUNSKMWKKS | 500000 | A |
| 09102021D093042 | HUSUEJJKS | 430000 | B |
| 09102021D093042 | JISKDSKEJD | 520000 | B |
| 09102021D114430 | 732UI32JE | 540000 | - |
| 09102021D114430 | 823JDEJJRD | 420000 | - |
| 09102021D114430 | 73823JEWN | 239999 | - |
| 09102021D123404 | NCDJJ73273 | 650000 | - |

Then I expect to detect that when I have :

- 2 lines ExecutionTime repeatedly the same and same Amount = TYPE 1
- 2 lines ExecutionTime repeatedly the same and same Mark = TYPE 2
- 3 lines ExecutionTime same =  Type 3
- from 4 lines ExecutionTime repeatedly = Type 4

I get that line to new dataframe like this:

| ExecutionTime | Code | Amount | Mark | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09102021D081020 | HUUSNJUNJ | 500000 | C | 1 |
| 09102021D093042 | HUSUEJJKS | 430000 | B | 2 |
| 09102021D114430 | 732UI32JE | 540000 | - | 3 |

Welcome to any idea and suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
df.loc[df['ExecutionTime'] == '09102021D081020', 'Type'] = '1'
df.loc[df['ExecutionTime'] == '09102021D093042', 'Type'] = '2'
df.loc[df['ExecutionTime'] == '09102021D114430', 'Type'] = '3'
df.loc[df['ExecutionTime'] == '09102021D123404', 'Type'] = '4'
```

Comment: Thank you but the dataset with 5000 lines and executionTime won't work like that :)

Comment: Could you provide a little more information and maybe share the dataset please?

Comment: I have dataset with executiontime in 6 months, every executiontime in dataset repeatedly multipletime, then I have to detect and tag them with type like this.